# playing an audio after another inside a loop in js

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, audio

I am still new to js and I tried to make a script that will play a sound related to the content in a way that when ever there is a positive sign the audio will say positive and after that it will check the next character and if it is positive again it will say positive for the second time or negative if that was the case and so on.
but for some reason the first audio works for one time and it doesn't keep playing sound for each character on newText.

```
var audioNegative = new Audio('/negative.mp3');
var audioPositive = new Audio('/positive.mp3');

var newText='+-+-+-++++--+-+';
        document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML = newText;
        for (var e = 0; e < newText.length; e++) {
           if(newText[e]=='+')
               {  
audioPositive.play();

               }
           if(newText[e]=='-')
               {           
audioNegative.play();

               }
           }
```

Comment: Your loop is synchronous, while playing a sound is not. By the time the first sound finishes, you loop will have ended already. You need to wait for the sound to play before going onto the next one

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setTimeout()` to delay when the audio is played.

```
var audioNegative = new Audio('/negative.mp3');
var audioPositive = new Audio('/positive.mp3');

var newText='+-+-+-++++--+-+';
document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML = newText;
for (var e = 0; e < newText.length; e++) {
    if(newText[e]=='+')
    {
        //Replace 1000 with your audio's length in ms
        setTimeout(() => audioPositive.play(), e * 1000);
    }
    if(newText[e]=='-')
    {
        //Replace 1000 with your audio's length in ms
        setTimeout(() => audioNegative.play(), e * 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting for a fixed delay, you can just wait for the sound to finish, no matter how long it is:

```js
var audios = {
  '-': new Audio('https://freesound.org/data/previews/377/377427_6996670-lq.mp3'),
  '+': new Audio('https://freesound.org/data/previews/414/414679_8162553-lq.mp3')
};
var $newText = document.getElementById('newText'),
    $playBtn = document.getElementById('playBtn');

$playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => playString($newText.value));

function playString(str) {
  if (str.length > 0) {
    const audio = audios[str[0]];
    if (audio) {
      audio.play();
      audio.onended = () => playString(str.substr(1));
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => playString(str.substr(1)), 500);
      // Or simply playString(str.substr(1)); if you don't want to pause
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="newText" value="--+--+--+++">
<button id="playBtn">Play</button>
```

Comment: this works only if all the positive and negative characters don't have space between them, when ever i input spaces in between the characters the whole thing crashes. is there a way to make it silence where ever there is space between the characters.

Comment: @billmiller Sure. I edited the answer. If a character is not in the list (+ or -), such as a space, it will pause for 500 milliseconds